# Configuration of send connector for Exchange 2010

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange-2010

I'm having a problem with the initial setup.
I need to add an (A) record and an (MX) record on my DNS server and am new to exchange.
Can anyone point me to a link for step by step, please

Roland

Comment: Is your DNS server running on a non-Windows machine or a machine outside your domain?

Comment: Please describe the situation that you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Is your domain active on the Internet, can you tell the name ?

You need to go to your DNS server, (or maybe it is your domain registar), and there on web interface, or if it is Microsoft DNS server, add DNS records.

So fist thing to know isWhich DNS server do you have ?